# is it a proper or improper integral? Why can the summation order and the integral be changed? I also need to know why f is improperly integrable

Tags: integration

Prove that if $f (x) = ∑_{n=1}^{∞}\frac{x^n}{n},0≤x<1$, then
$∫_{0}^{1} f(x)dx = ∑_{n=1}^{∞} \frac{1}{n(n+1)}$

Solution

$f (x) = ∑_{n=1}^{∞} \frac{x^n}{n}→ ∫f (x) dx = ∑_{n=1}^{∞}∫\frac{x^n}{n}dx = ∑_{n=1}^{∞}\frac{x^{n+1}}{n(n+1)}+ C →$

$∫_{0}^{1}f(x)dx=[∑_{n=1}^{∞}\frac{x^{n+1}}{n(n+1}]]_{0}^{1}=∑_{n=1}^{∞}\frac{1}{n(n+1)}−0= ∑_{n=1}^{∞}\frac{1}{n(n+1)}$

is it a proper or improper integral?

Why can the summation order and the integral be changed?
I also need to know why f is improperly integrable

Answer (score 1):

$f(x) \to \sum \frac 1 n=\infty$ as $ x \to 1-$. So $f$ is not a bounded function. The integral is therefore an improper integral.

Compute the proper integral $\int_0^{t} f(x)dx$ by your method for $t <1$ and take the limit. The series $\sum \frac {t^{n+1}} {n(n+1)}$ is uniformly convergent (by M-Test) and this justifies the computation by interchanging the limit (as $ t $ increases to $1$) and the sum over $n$.

Comment: Thank very much!